# Web Service Trimming Starting Zeros

Tags: jquery, web-services, http-get

I already found a workaround fix but not sure why it causes this, so I can fix it properly without a "workaround"

I have a web service method..

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string Validate(string value)
{
}
```

I have a javascript method that calls this method..

```
function CheckABAValidation() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../Service/MyWebService.asmx/Validate',
        data: { value: $('#tbValue').val() },
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is, when I type `021214156` in `tbValue`, when I step through to the WebService.. value is `21214156`, however if I do `alert($('#tbValue').val());` it does show `021214156`, so it appears that the web service is seeing a number before it gets to the web service..

Tried with no success:

```
data: { value: new String($('#tbValue').val()) },
```

```
data: { value: $('#tbValue').val().toString() },
```

Fix I did was changing:

```
data: { value: $('#tbValue').val() },
```

To:

```
data: { value: ' " ' + $('#tbValue').val() + ' " ' },
```

Is there a better way to make the web service know that this is a string and not a number, even tho string is the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out..

was

```
data: JSON.stringify({ value: $('#tbValue').val() }),
```

this was due to my web service has

```
ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json
```